# can not update an image of a cell in table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am doing customized cell for uitable view like below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier    =   @"overViewCell";
    tableCell                   =   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if ( tableCell == nil ) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        tableCell           =   overViewCell;
        self.overViewCell   =   nil;
    }
    ..............................................................
}
```

and OverViewCell.xib looks like ( the right image is tagged as 3 )

[image]

And later, I would like to change the image of particular cell from the table view by doing this

```
- (void) updateImageView {
    // currentRow is getting value when cellForRowAtIndex is clicked  
    NSIndexPath *indexPath  =   [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentRow inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell   =   [self.tableContent cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    imageView               =   (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    imageView.image         =   [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

However, the image is not changed at all

What I am missing in the middle... Please help if you have any clues about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured what the problem is. it is because I was assigning the wrong tag to that image